# How does ArrayAdapter<T> work with items?

Tags: java, android

I have an instance of `AutoCompleteTextView` supported by an instance of `ArrayAdapter<String>`. I noticed that when I remove an item from this adapter using `remove(T)` method and after that I use `for()` loop to write all items from this adapter using `getItem(int)`, it writes even removed item but when I click on the instance of `AutoCompleteTextView` and the `ListView` with items is displayed and I use `for()` loop to write all items now it outputs correctly without removed item. I don't know why it removes items not after calling `remove(T)` but after `ListView` is displayed even when I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after `remove(T)` call. Thanks for any reply.

Look at this example:
When you type **a** to the `AutoCompleteTextView` you will see 4 items and when you press **Write items** button you will see all 4 items logged. When you press **Delete 3rd item** button it will remove this item from the adapter then it will call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and after that it will write all items and there you will see that there will be removed item too. But when you type **a** to the `AutoCompleteTextView` again, now you will see 3 items and when you press **Write items** now it will write only 3 items except removed one.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/auto_et"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:completionThreshold="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Write items"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="logItems" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete 3rd item"
        android:onClick="deleteItem" />


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AutoCompleteTextView auto_et = null;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("ab");
        list.add("abc");
        list.add("abcd");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
        auto_et = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.auto_et);
        auto_et.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void logItems(View v) {
        for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); ++i) {
            Log.d(null, adapter.getItem(i));
        }
    }

    public void deleteItem(View v) {
        adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(2));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        logItems(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you start tipying something in your `AutocompleteTextView` you enter in filtering mode. The `ArrayAdapter` keeps a copy of the original dataset and use this copy to filter out the dataset and present the data to the user. Keeping a copy, it has always the possibility to restore the original dataset. This copy is created the first time you ask for filtering. As for the filtering mechanism, `getItem` and `getCount` will work on the filtered dataset. `ArrayAdapter.remove(T)`, removes the item from the copy, if it is not null, while `getItem` keeps using the filtered values. When you delete chars from the `AutocompleteTextView` the copy is used to clean up the data and update the ui. In your case it contains all items but the third one. You can have a look to the code of the `ArrayAdapter` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.remove%28java.lang.Object%29)